SOQL AVG unexpected behaviour, incorrect result
Background:
I'm working through my Trailhead to get those points and badges.  I start doing the Advanced Apex Testing trail as it should be a relatively easy one for me.  I should have already finished it.
I'm on the third step: "Write Positive Tests" and it compiles and runs correctly the first time. Then I go about expanding the unit test to achieve what is expected from the test and I'm seeing some odd behaviour from an aggregate query doing an average on test Opportunity records.
Problem:

Account: 1
Opportunity: 5

Account: Linked to the above
Stage: Prospecting
Amount: 1000.00



There is a query which happens in a tested function which does the following:
SELECT AVG(Amount)
FROM Opportunity
WHERE AccountId = :testAccountId
WITH USER_MODE

And this is returning with the average amount being: 1136.36.
I'm only working in VS Code while doing these changes, nothing has been changed in my Org since well before the first pass of this test where the above code was working.
I break it down and remove all data from my Org.  I have one Account and one Opportunity.  The Opportunity has the Amount: 1000, like above.
Running a SELECT Id, StageName, Amount FROM Opportunity in my Org returns the one Opportunity record with its Id, StageName (Prospecting at this point), and 1000.00 as the Amount.
Running a SELECT AVG(Amount) FROM Opportunity returns:
AVG(Amount): 1136.36.
I play around the the Amount values and StageNames and the only consistency is that the amount the Average has been inflated by always seems to be: 7.3529%.
Any suggestions?
Edit 1: So that additional information is easier to find
The extra testing that was done was not in a test class, it was directly in my Org, having removed all other Accounts and Opportunities before hand.  So only the 1 Account and 1 Opportunity existed. Calculating the average by querying all Opportunities and doing the maths manually (directly in my Org & the unit test) did return the expected result, however that's what the Aggregate function AVG is for, right?
@SeeAllData=true is not in use anywhere in my testing.  There are no triggers on Opportunity.

In your @isTest annotation at the top of your test class include seeAllData=true? If so, that's generally bad practice (data for tests should be created within the test class itself, usually as part of a @testSetup annotated method). Beyond that, do you have any triggers or flows from a previous trailhead unit that may be adjusting the Opportunity amount (or adding in additional OpportunityLineItems?). Another thing to look at is to write another query without the AVG(), just pulling the Amount field itself, loop over it, and system.debug() the Opportunity.

@DerekF There is no seeAllData=true.  The extra 'testing' was done in my Org with only the 1 Account and 1 Opportunity records existing.  Outside of a test environment.
Also when querying the records into a list [SELECT Amount FROM Opportunity] and finding the average manually, the result was as expected, and didn't have the artificial inflation on it.

Is it still the same manually-calculated average if you factor in deleted rows? (i.e. try [SELECT Amount FROM Opportunity ALL ROWS]). That's about the only other thing I can think of (though the aggregate function grabbing deleted rows would strike me as a bug if that is the cause).

@DerekF The result is the same, yes.  It's the same whether in a Test class or just in the Org itself while using the AVG aggregate function.
I am quite baffled.

any chance this is a currency issue?

@cropredy It turns out it was a currency issue, thank you!  Although I'm baffled as to why the first test run passed, it is now passing since I disabled all other currencies and set the exchange rate to 1.  I double checked on the test data and it is setting the currency to USD while my user is in EUR.
Once again, thank you!  Please post it as an answer so I can mark it solved. :)

Given that your test involved only a single Opportunity and you

Expected 1000.00
Got 1136.36

the suspicion is that this is a currency discrepancy (an exchange rate of 1: 1.136 sounds suggests EUR: USD) amongst:

the running user's currency
the Opportunity.CurrencyIsoCode
Org default currency

